# Extracting day with lubridate

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a date column, but it's written all the way around, Ex: "31-12-2019"
When I try to extract the day using the `day()` function from lubridate : `day("31-12-2019")` it returns "19" instead of "31"

PS : I've already tried to change to column type using `as.Date`, but it reorders my data and I don't want that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to first convert to `Date` class and then apply the `day`

```
library(lubridate)
day(as.Date("31-12-2019", "%d-%m-%Y"))
#[1] 31
```

Or with `dmy`

```
day(dmy("31-12-2019"))
```

Comment: Or `day(dmy("31-12-2019"))` since the OP is already loading package `lubridate`.